# Test more than 3 soldiers for Psi abilities

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I'm playing Xcom-Enemy Within.

Apparently, I can only build 1 Psi lab. And the Psi lab only test 3 soldiers taking 10 days.

That way it will take a lifetime to check on everyone.
It will also take a million years until I find soldiers with high will.

Is there a way to test more than 3 soldiers per 10 days?

If not, is there a way to verify what soldier has the ability or not? Any tricks?

Comment: There's [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87741/what-determines-if-a-soldier-is-gifted-with-psionic-powers), but I'm unsure if enemy within changes the mechanics.

Comment: This savescumming is totally fine by me! That's actually exactly what I was looking for!
If we could create like 4 psi labs, I would probably not use any strategy. But since it is not possible, this one does not look like cheating. It's just a time saving process.

Comment: It's really not that long. I regularly have all my non-squaddies tested pretty quick, and squaddies normally get tested before they have to fight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty much a hard limit, unless you use the [savescumming strategies described here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87741/what-determines-if-a-soldier-is-gifted-with-psionic-powers).

A soldier's will appears to influence the chance that they'll be gifted, but there's no way to tell for sure without doing the testing, because that's when the decision is actually made.

In vanilla XCOM: EW (i.e. not playing Long War) 10 days isn't all that long of a time, so it's generally feasible to just stick one high-rank soldier and a couple of lower-rank soldiers in that you don't mind losing for 10 days at a time.